Thinkpad P1G7 internal display periodically freezes while laptop is otherwise working fine
I have a 2024 Thinkpad P1G7 on Windows 10, fully-patched and fully updated with drivers. I've had a problem since I got the laptop new that periodically the built-in LCD display freezes up. If I have external displays connected, they continue to function fine, and if I close and open the laptop, the internal display returns to normal.
Has anyone seen behavior like this?
I talked to Lenovo premium tech support and the only suggestion they had was returning to Thinkpad OEM display drivers, which I did, but it made no difference. So I've tried both the latest Lenovo drivers as well as the latest Intel drivers and still see this behavior every day or so. I've also had the motherboard replaced due to an unrelated USB issue -- this would mean a new GPU and new video card -- same behavior.
Physically closing/opening the lid is an easy workaround although it is annoying if I'm in a video call since I disappear for a minute.
As far as I can tell, nothing else goes wrong when this happens--no errors in Event Viewer, and all processes on external displays function completely normally.
Any ideas how to troubleshoot or fix?
Windows 10 Version 22H2 (OS Build 10945.5247)
Intel Arc Graphics Driver 32.0.101.6314 (but as noted, this also occurs with the Lenovo OEM driver)
Nvidia GeForce RTX 4070 GPU 32.0.15.6094
BIOS N48ET22W (1.09), 9/26/2024
System Model 21KWS0K600


+1 for clear question.

Lenovo drivers are the same drivers as the Intel drivers, only older, I definitely would try the current drivers here make sure you have the the new Nvidia App and the current drivers instead of the legacy GeForce Experience, if none of that helps then you likey have a hardware problem not a software problem

That was my instinct as well--reverting to Lenovo drivers wasn't going to help. I have done the Intel Driver & Support Assistant and updated to the latest there, but I'll see if there are any newer drivers available for direct download. Note I don't think it's an Nvidia issue--my understanding is the GPU powers the external displays while the Intel graphics card powers the internal display. When the internal display freezes, the external displays are fine. But I will check the new Nvidia App as well and report back.
